# Is there a way to prevent certain javascript functions from accessing a jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

Situation:

- On a single webpage I am using Syntax Highlighter and Lightbox 2
- Syntax Highlighter uses JavaScript. Lightbox 2 uses jQuery (version 1.7.2)
- When I run each of the scripts on independently(different pages), it works
- Problem only occurs when I run both on the same page
- On Google Chrome, web page runs perfectly
- On IE 8 I get an error when a part of the lightbox2 function is called
- Error points to jquery1.7.2 file stating method/property not supported by this object
- Code for the exact line of error is: parts = rfxnum.exec(val);
- I inserted an alert() to show me vlaues for both rfxnum and val
- rfxnum=/^([+-]=)?([\d+.-]+)([a-z%]*)$/i
- val = 802
- The crazy thing I discovered is that when I run the two scripts independently the alert shows identical values for rfxnum and val, and yet it runs fine.
- Syntax Highlighter runs fine in all conditions

My Guess:
-Syntax Highlighter seems to be interfering w/ values/functions/parameters in jQuery 1.7.2 library. OR some global value that both syntax highlighter and jQuery library reference.

My Question:

- Is there a way to prevent Syntax Highlighter or any other non-jQuery JS script to NOT interact/reference the jQuery lib.
- If the answer is, JavaScript won't reference jQuery libs in the first place, then my question is what are some possible reasons that something like this occurs.
- Alternatively, is there a way to package the jQuery lib and relevant JS functions together so that no other functions could reference any of the functions/variables in the package

I would appreciate any suggestions/insights.

Comment: If possible please make a sample in http://jsbin.com/ so that others will get a better idea.

Comment: Can try to wrap "no jquery code" with self invoking anonymous function (function() { .. })(); and/or use jquery noconflict $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });

Answer (score 2):

You can [use noConflict()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries&redirect=no)

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.
```

Using jQuery.noConflict(); - [Lightbox and jQuery conflict](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-jquery-noconflict-lightbox-and-jquery-conflict)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read about noconflict before but i still have trouble understaning how to actually use it. In my above situation, do i go and replace every single $ with $j? or do i put $j infront of all my functions? ($j.function(){.

Comment: Its clearly there in the first link..seee second paraghraph ..use like jQuery.noConflict();
 
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

Comment: Sincere apologies, first time at this form and didn't notice the link under the code example. I've gone through everything in the link you gave me, tried everything i could w/ no conflict. Conclusion is i dont think its noconflict issue. A)All attempts failed w/ noconflict B) Most of the posts on the link you have provided disscusses jquery vs jquery. This case is js(non-jquery) vs jquery and no use of $ in the js script. C) why work in google chrome at all if it were a noconflict problem. Either way thanks for your advise, helped me understand a bit more about no conflict.